# In-memory thumbnail generation in python

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, gridfs

I store uploaded images in gridfs (mongodb). Therefore, the image data is never saved on the normal filesystem. This works by using the following code:

```
import pymongo
import gridfs

conn = pymongo.Connection()
db = conn.my_gridfs_db
fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)

...
    with fs.new_file(
        filename = 'my-filename-1.png',
    ) as fp:
        fp.write(image_data_as_string)
```

I also want to store thumbnails of that image. I do not care which library to use, PIL, Pillow, sorl-thumbnail or whatever fits best will work for me.

I want to know if there is a way to generate thumbnails without temporarily saving the file in the filesystem. That would be much cleaner and less overhead. Is there an in-memory thumbnail generator?

### Update

My solution to save the thumbnail:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
content = cStringIO.StringIO()
content(icon)
image = Image.open(content)

temp_content = cStringIO.StringIO()
thumb = ImageOps.fit(image, (width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
thumb.save(temp_content, format='png')
temp_content.seek(0)
gridfs_image_data = temp_content.getvalue()

with fs.new_file(
    content_type = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0],
    filename = filename,
    size = size,
    width = width,
    height = height,
) as fp:
    fp.write(gridfs_image_data)
```

The file is then served via [nginx-gridfs](https://github.com/mdirolf/nginx-gridfs).

Comment: You can substitute file objects with `StringIO`, so you can do it with just about any imaging library.

Comment: thanks! make that an answer with an example included and i'll accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save it to a [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) object instead of a file (use the `cStringIO` module, if possible):

```
from StringIO import StringIO

fake_file = StringIO()
thing.save(fake_file)  # Acts like a file handle
contents = fake_file.getvalue()
fake_file.close()
```

Or if you like context managers:

```
import contextlib
from StringIO import StringIO

with contextlib.closing(StringIO()) as handle:
    thing.save(handle)
    contents = handle.getvalue()
```

Comment: got a problem with generating the thumbnails, i updated my question

Comment: @Alp: `ImageOps.fit` doesn't seem like it takes a file object. Shouldn't you be passing an image object in there?

Comment: you are right, i updated my question once more because i got a new problem